# Export objects from class issue

Tags: php, pimcore

I have a product export and I try to export all objects using my custom plugins. I'm using below method to load all objects

```
        $list = new Pimcore_Model_Object_Bodproduct();
        $list->setOrder ( "ASC" );
        $list->setOrderKey ( "o_id" );

        // Load all filtered objects - products
        $list->load ();
```

Then i'm using foreach loop to access the objects.

It's working fine. But the problem is it's taking lot of time to export. Is there any other solutions for this .. I mean instead of `load()` function, is there any other method is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$list->loadIdList()` to fetch only object IDs - which should be faster. Then you can call `Object::getById($id)` within loop to provide progress bar (assuming your script is launched in console).

In fact this is what `load()` is doing internally, please see [Object\Listing\Resource class](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/blob/master/pimcore/models/Object/Listing/Resource.php#L68)

Another option is to split load to many "pages" by calling `$list->getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage)`.

Comment: Thanks, this is also nice solution. But actually I messed up in my foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

In Pimcore object listing, you can *traverse* each object in list without calling a `load` method. In your case, just remove `"$list->load ();"` and see it will work with less time.